# Constraint layout: Cannot separate elements and keep them all on screen

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a simple constraint layout like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/main_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/rescan"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/rescan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/rescan_button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Despite the `layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/rescan"`, the listview potentially extends halfway through the button.

[image]

To try and correct that, I added hardcoded dimensions (which I prefer not to do); to the listview:

```
android:layout_marginBottom="50sp"
```

And to the button:

```
android:layout_height="40sp"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:layout_margin="10sp"
```

However, I then got this (emulator pic, the design view also corresponds to this):

[image]

The button is halfway off the screen.

So I decided to remove the hardcoded dimensions and use **a barrier.**  The [developer page](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/) is ambiguous about how `barrierDirection` is supposed to work, but [this 
"constraintlayout.com" example](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/barriers.html) makes it clear the direction should be the side you want the barrier on in relation to the elements listed in `referenced_ids`.  Based on that, here's what I have inside the constraint layout:

```xml
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/main_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomBarrier"
    />

<android.support.constraint.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/bottomBarrier"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:barrierDirection="top"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="@id/rescan"
    />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/rescan"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/rescan_button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    />
```

But things are not really getting better...

[image]

It's impossible to tell, but here the barrier is *at the very bottom*.  Which explains why the listview, with `Bottom_toTopOf` the barrier, also now extends all the way to the bottom.

However, that makes the whole barrier, who's direction is `top` and who's constrained id is the button, **totally pointless**.  In no sense is it keeping the listview on one side and the button on the other.  It's below both of them.

Even more berserk: If I change the direction to `bottom` and leave everything else as it, the barrier jumps to the very top, the listview jumps halfway off the screen upward, and the button stays in place.

I'm totally flummoxed. My two biggest questions are:

1. Why, in the first picture, does the listview extend halfway through the button, when it is set bottom-to-top of the button?
2. Why, in the last picture, is the barrier, with a direction of "top" and referencing the button id, *below* the button?

Comment: "I have a simple constraint layout like this" -- it refers to a widget (`rescan`) that does not exist in the layout. It has two `main_list` widgets.

Comment: I had some issues with this recently. Could you possibly try changing your constraint Ids to `@+id` and see if that fixes it?

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks -- that was a result of cutting and pasting it to an intermediate editor so I could purge superfluous colorscheme stuff.  I cut and pasted the typo version back into studio (where it won't work at all with the duplicate ids), and fixed the typo to make sure it does what I said it does above, with the typo also now corrected.

Comment: @w9jds It doesn't make any difference, although it also shows it as an error in the editor.

Comment: In Android Studio 3.1, I am not seeing "the listview potentially extended halfway through the button" in the preview or on hardware, with `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0`. That being said, replace `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` with `android:layout_height="0dp"` for the `ListView`, since you are trying to stretch it between two anchor points. Also, do not use `match_parent` on children of `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: Aside for the obvious errors (using `match_parent` for example), why are you using a Barrier to begin with? If you want the list to be pinned to the top of the button why don’t you just pin the button/list like so?

Comment: @MartinMarconcini That's the first version above: "Despite the `layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/rescan"`, the listview potentially extends halfway through the button."  I tried also using a top to bottom constraint on the button, and every combination of the two.

Comment: @CommonsWare I think the initial version was confusing in that I presented the layout with hardcoded dimensions that I said I had added to correct the halfway through the button problem.  So for what it is worth I've clarified that above; using constraint layo v. 1.1.0 in studio v. 3.1.2, if I cut and paste the first layout (now) in the question, I get the first picture.  If I then add the hardcoded dimensions mentioned above, I get the second picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
Your `ListView's` height is set to `wrap_content` which means the view will compute its own size and constraints will not limit the dimension. `ConstraintLayout-1.1.0` introduced new attributes that allow using `wrap_content` yet keep enforcing the constraints to limit the specified dimension. These attribues are:

```
app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
```

2.
As for the `Barrier`, there's an error in the way you're referencing the view's id:

```
app:constraint_referenced_ids="@id/rescan"
```

This should be changed to:

```
app:constraint_referenced_ids="rescan"
```

Comment: Looking at the tutorial I linked, the example there does not use `@id` -- whoops, thanks.  That with the `constrainedHeight` and things now look like I want them to.